# Sonar + Blockers not appearing in Analysis

Tags: sonarqube

I have a Java class with some code that should appear in Sonar as blockers but... they're not showing at all. I just get Critical and Majors. I've checked the rules for Blockers and I'm doing the stuff that breaks them but nothing appears, and the project is using the profile with this rules so... Any clue of what it's going on?

```
public class ThisBreaksEverything {

    public ThisBreaksEverything() {
         System.out.println("I shouldn't use syso.");
         // Downcast
         Object o = new Object();
         String s = (String) o;
     }

     void breakingMethod() {
         // ClassCastException.
         Object x = new Integer(0);
         System.out.println((String)x);
     }

     String[] getAsArray(Collection<String> c) {
         return (String[]) c.toArray();
     }

     boolean twoDifferentTypesOfArrays() {
         String[] strings = new String[2];
         int[] ints = new int[3];
         return strings.equals(ints); 
     }

     public boolean equals(Object o) { 
         // Always True
         return this == this; 
     }
```

Comment: What are the rules? Has the compiled code been made available to SonarQube (sonar.java.binaries property)?

Comment: Thanks! I was giving the .source property but not the .binaries. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the rule is activated in the Quality Profile?

Comment: Yes, they are. Even if I filter them by "Activation: Active", they appear as well.